# How do I make a comment?

Tags: discussion, support, comment, privileges

For some reason I can make comments on my own posts, but then when I try to make comments on other people's posts or anything else for that matter, a blue notification pops up saying I require 50 reputation. Can someone please explain why this is or if there is any way around it? Or perhaps this is just a bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Testing 1, 2,3 to see if I can make a comment.
**Edit**: So I can only make comments on my own posts...Strange.

Comment: @robjohn  Ok thanks, but can you explain why there restrictions on commenting? From what I know Stackexchange has one of the the worst account deletion systems and a whole series of perhaps unnecessary restrictions making noobs much more trapped in their places.

Comment: If you have ever participated in some older generation of public math forums, then you will be shocked by the trolls in how effective they are in turning a forum into a hell of flame wars. The restriction on SE seems strange, but it seems it is at least working. I'll prefer one that works with some restriction than one completely not usable. Remember, not everyone is as nice and sensible as you.

Comment: @achillehui ok thx haha

Comment: Some older related posts: [How to make a remark when reputation is under 50?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9203/how-to-make-a-remark-when-reputation-is-under-50) and
[Should we really have a reputation requirement for commenting?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12228/should-we-really-have-a-reputation-requirement-for-commenting) (Maybe you could have a look at other posts tagged [comment+privileges](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comment+privileges) to see whether you find there some information which is useful for you.

Comment: @MartinSleziak ok thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757) says

> All users may leave comments on their own posts and any answers given to their own questions. Users with **at least 50 reputation** may comment on any post. (There is no reputation requirement to post comments on MSO only; doing so elsewhere, including on other meta sites, requires 50 reputation.)

Comment: Ok, same comment: Ok thanks, but can you explain why there restrictions on commenting? From what I know Stackexchange has one of the the worst account deletion systems and a whole series of perhaps unnecessary restrictions making noobs much more trapped in their places.

Comment: This is just a guess as I have no insight into the motives of the developers, but I believe that there is a restriction on adding comments to keep random individuals from simply joining and adding malicious comments.

Comment: oh ok thx so much